# Toolbar And Unity in games

Tags: 11.04, unity, wine, games

I've searched the internet a few times now and can't find a answer that helps me.

When I play games such as Dawn Of War, the toolbar on the top half of my screen won't go in the background and neither will Unity. 
So I'm just hoping there's a way around this.

I've just started using Ubuntu (11.04) and on all other fronts I'm very pleased with it.

So I'm hoping someone out there can help me. This little tweak to Ubuntu would make it make it an all around fantastic experience for a newbie like me.

Comment: I'm giving you a vote up just for mentioning Dawn of War.....and its a good question

Answer (score 1):

I usually encounter this while playing some games in fullscreen via wine.

You can try <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch some windows, and then return to the game.

Also, you can try playing in emulated virtual desktop (check Graphics tab in winecfg). Works best with the same size of your screen and unchecked "Allow window manager to decorate the windows" option.

Also, check [Wine HQ](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1918) for possible bugs/solutions in your version of Dawn Of War.